# fs.stat failing to identify existing files

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, file-io, filesystems, fs

I am using `async.each` to check through an array of 180 filenames, using `fs.stat` to check that the physical file exists. At present, all the files do exist, and yet every time I call this code, 3 of the 180 images are found by `fs.stat` to be non-existent. The images which it fails to find vary slightly on each call.

The first image which fails to be found is always around the 70th filename in the array. If I reduce the size of the array to a list of (for example) 50 names, then all the images are found.

```
// ImagesToCheck is an array of 180 filepaths, all of which exist on the server

var index = 0

async.each(ImagesToCheck,
function(item, cb) {

    fs.stat(item, function(error, value) {
        if (error) {
            // Logs "ENOENT: no such file or directory"
            console.log("error is "+error)
            // this is logging the correct filename, which DOES exist
            console.log("filename is "+ImagesToCheck[index]) 

            Speakers[index].speaker_image_url = null
            index++
            cb()
        } 
        else {
            // Image exists
            // console.log("image exists " + index)
            Speakers[index].speaker_image_url = "http://www.apiurl.co.uk/images/seminar_image-" + rows[index].seminar_id + ".jpg"
            index++
            cb()
        }
    }) // close fs.stat
},
function(err) {
    // sends the array of URLs
    callBack(Speakers)
})
```

// Now using fs.open instead of fs.stat, with async.forEachOf, and getting basically the same result:

```
var index = 0

async.forEachOf(ImagesToCheck,
    function(item, key, cb) {

        fs.open(item, 'r', function(error, value) {
            if (error) {
                // Logs "ENOENT: no such file or directory"
                console.log("error is " + error)
                    // this is logging the correct filename, which DOES        exist
                console.log("index is " + index + ", filename is " +  ImagesToCheck[index])
                Speakers[index].speaker_image_url = null
                index++
                return cb()
            }

            // if no error
            Speakers[index].speaker_image_url =   "http://www.apiurl.co.uk/images/seminar_image-" + rows[index].seminar_id + ".jpg"
            index++
            cb()
        })
    },
    function(err) {
    // send the array of urls
    callBack(Speakers)
    }
)
```

Comment: The index will give you no useful information as it is now, since it may be updated before the printing. Use `async.eachOf` to get the real index

Comment: I changed it to forEachOf and it is still behaving in the same way! Will post the code in a sec...

Comment: Just made a test implementation, no error when checking 200 files

Comment: There is no `forEachOf` in latest versions of async, are you sure you are using the right version of async? Also, now that you have the id, do you see a pattern in the missings files?

Comment: I did npm install async a couple of days ago so I think it would be the latest version.

Comment: In that case, could you try the code I posted below, replacing the `files` variable by your own array?

Comment: okay I will give that a try and get back to you shortly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is just to show a test implementation. This is not intended as a answer*

Just tried to generate 200 files (0.txt, 1.txt... 200.txt) in a folder named `files`, and tried this code:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async');

let files = [],
    results = [],
    i = 0;

while(i < 200) {
    files.push('./files/' + i + '.txt');
    i = i + 1;
}

async.eachOf(files, (file, i, callback) => {
    fs.stat(file, (err, stats) => {
        files[i] = !err;
        callback();
    });
}, () => {
    let notFound = files.filter((f) => {
        return !f;
    });
    console.log('fs.stat didn\'t found ' + notFound.length + '/200 files');
    files.map((f, i) => {
        if(!f) {
            console.log('File ' + i + ' wasn\'t found');
        }
    })
});
```

No error found, it seems the problem is not `fs.stat`

Comment: I have tried the above, it doesn't find any of the files. "File not found" is logged for each one. I used an absolute file path and placed them in the same directory as the files from my original API. Also the request "hangs" - the app as a whole doesn't crash, just the specific url that I am using for your example hangs for ages with no additional error being logged.

Comment: Could you post a example of `filesToCheck`? Also, since the problem is on `fs.stats`, I d recommend you build a MCVE out of your real code, without searching the URL, to understand where is your error, and put the right code back into the real app.

Comment: sorry what does filesToCheck refer to?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have got it working now! There were in fact three missing images, but these were not always the ones that were being returned as null - the index being found wasn't matching the actual image which fs.stat failed to locate, I think because I was attempting to use an iterating index (not part of ImageToCheck) within the first error handler of fs.stat. Now I've made ImagesToCheck an object and am referring to an individual member by its key it seems to work.

Comment: You could also use the index of `async.eachOf`, without transforming the format of `ImagesToCheck`